Make AMD GPU available in Docker container
I am running g4ad family instances on AWS. I am running there docker containers where I need to access the AMD GPUs.
The used AMI for host instance is Amazon Linux 2 optimised for AMD.
The base image for Docker is ubuntu:22.04.
I am trying to follow the instructions written on AWS web.
I tried different version of amdgpu-install.
When I run amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation --vulkan=pro --opencl=rocr,legacy -y I am always getting E: Unable to locate package vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386.
So I my main problem is that I cannot finish properly the installation of GPU inside the Docker container.
